# Comparing string input to multiple strings Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to filter out the String inputs if they match a particular phrase in string format. For this I tried sets as well as Switch Case.Butfor both scenarios keywords with spaces are not being filtered .i.e. "NOT APPLICABLE","I NO LONGER HAVE THIS DATA","I DON'T KNOW",'WILL PROVIDE LATER' are not being filtered

```
   Sets Example :
 let inputStringUppercase= inputString.toUpperCase().trim(); 
 let keywordsToFilter = new Set();                
keywordsToFilter.add('N/A').add('NA').add('UNKNOWN').add('NONE').add('NOT APPLICABLE').add('I NO LONGER H AVE THIS DATA').add("I DON'T KNOW").add('WILL PROVIDE LATER').add('?').add('null').add('NULL');
 if (keywordsToFilter.has(CapsAdjusterName)) {
              
                    sails.log.info(inputString, ' is invalid ');
                }
```

```
Switch Example :
let inputStringUppercase= inputString.toUpperCase().trim();
switch (inputStringUppercase) {
                     case 'NULL':
                     case 'N/A':
                     case 'NA':
                     case 'NONE':
                     case "NOT APPLICABLE":
                     case "I NO LONGER HAVE THIS DATA":
                     case "I DON\'T KNOW":
                     case 'WILL PROVIDE LATER':
                     case '?':
                     case 'UNKNOWN':
                     case 'null':
                
                     validitycheck= true;
                }
                  if(validitycheck){
                    sails.log.info(inputString, ' is invalid AdjusterName');
                   }
```

Comment: I tried the switch and it works as expected

Comment: You can remove the \ in `"I DON\'T KNOW"` though since you're using double quotes escaping is not needed